# Need to create flipbook view of file in angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular7

I am working with file in pdf format in angular 7 application. I have to show its preview as a flipbook in new window.
I have found one javascript application for the reference but unable to integrate it with angular app. I have one javascript application as on below url `https://github.com/erayakartuna/pdf-flipbook`.

In my angular 7 application I have created the component named `Preview` which I am calling on button click from some other component.

As the javascript application having its all `js` as well as `css` files and `preview.html` file, I have copied all `JS and CSS` files into `assets` folder.

I had replaced preview component's template url with `preview.html` of javascript application. In the `preview.html` having  tag which calls the JS function but it is not working with angular 7 application.

This is the structure of my application,

[image: Directory Structure of Preview Component having js Application]

Code of component selector and templateUrl,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-preview',
  templateUrl: './preview.html',
  styleUrls: ['./preview.component.scss']
})
export class PreviewComponent implements OnInit {
        .
        .
     }
```

code of `Preview.html` calling js function,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/pdf-flip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {       

        PdfFlip.init();
    });
</script>
```

but as per execution I came to know that , function called from `preview.html` i.e `PdfFlip.init()` is not executing. So javascript application doesn't execute.
Can anyone help me to figure out issue?

Comment: Is this working now? I am facing similar issue.